# How do I delay ajax calls to the server in javascript?

Tags: jquery

For the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    $("div#main").on("keyup", "input[name=code]", function() {
        delay($.getJSON("/some-url/", function(data) {
            console.log("here");
        }), 2000);
    });

});
</script>

<div id="main">
  <input name="code" />
</div>
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the javascript error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I am trying to delay sending keyup data to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just forgotten to pass `delay` a function definition. Just tweak your event handler slightly (everything else stays the same):

```
$("div#main").on("keyup", "input[name=code]", function() {
    delay(function() { // <-----
        $.getJSON("/some_url/", function(data) {
            console.log("here");
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/f7F7c/

Comment: That code will run the Ajax call 2 seconds after every keypress, not 2 seconds after stopping typing.

Comment: @Archer I don't think you're correct... The `clearTimeout` call followed by a `setTimeout` in `delay` will reset the timer to two seconds from the `keyup`. Feel free to try it out in the fiddle :)

Comment: I see - that's not replacement code for his code.  He just needs to replace part of it with what you've done.  Sorry, that wasn't clear.

Comment: No problem, I'll amend my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like autocomplete to me?  Try this instead...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = 0;

    function runAjax() {
        $.getJSON("/some-url/", function(data) {
            console.log("here");
        });
    }

    $("div#main").on("keyup", "input[name=code]", function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(runAjax, 2000);
    });

});
</script>

<div id="main">
  <input name="code" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you at all: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYXp4/8/

This simply adds a delay when typing each time the keyup action is fired.  try the jsfiddle to see it in action.  You can do your ajax call after the delay has occurred no probs ^^

```
<input id="in" type="text"/>
<div id="out"></div>

var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#in').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#in').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            //do stuff here e.g ajax call etc....
             var v = $("#in").val();
             $("#out").html(v);
        }, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});
```